# Calculation help for Database Column Sum to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, stored-procedures

In my ASP.NET page I have a gridview that when you enter edit mode you can manually enter values to save to a database. One of my database columns is an "amount" column with different amounts pertaining to the user entries for a particular year.

What I am looking for is a calculation, either in my SQL procedure or in code behind, to add the amounts of the user entries into the amount column together and display them in a textbox on my asp.net page all in one fluid motion. Here is the code I used in sql for storing data to the database is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData]
@amt money,
@date datetime,
@cmmt nvarchar(255),
@int nvarchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [DB1].[dbo].[BE_AdjustBudgetTbl]
([BE_Adj_AMOUNT],[BE_Adj_APPRV_D],[BE_Adj_COMMENT],[BE_Adj_Initials]) 
VALUES (@amt,@date,@cmmt,@int)

END
```

Currently, I am just pulling the entered values from to amount columna and pasting them in my textbox without the calculation part which doesn't serve the purpose if there are multiple records:

```
 txtTotal.Text = txtTotal.ToString + amt
 Dim calc As Double = Convert.ToString(Double.Parse(txtIntAppr.Text) + txtTotal.Text)
 txtTotalAll.Text = Convert.ToInt32(calc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your stored procedure to do the calculation

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData] 
@amt money, 
@date datetime, 
@cmmt nvarchar(255), 
@int nvarchar(3),
@total money output
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

INSERT INTO [DB1].[dbo].[BE_AdjustBudgetTbl] 
([BE_Adj_AMOUNT],[BE_Adj_APPRV_D],[BE_Adj_COMMENT],[BE_Adj_Initials])  
VALUES (@amt,@date,@cmmt,@int) 

SELECT @total = SUM(BE_Adj_AMOUNT) 
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[BE_AdjustBudgetTbl]
WHERE Year([BE_Adj_APPRV_D]) = year(getdate())



END
```

Add the output parameter to your stored procedure call, with direction set to `ParameterDirection.Output`

Comment: I keep getting this error: ['Must declare the scalar variable "@output".'] And this only solves part of the problem, I need is to sum only the totals for the current year not everything in the column?

Comment: 1. Yes, my mistake - corrected
2. I've added a filter to the above answer